# array list object as implicit parameter

Tags: java, arraylist

Can an array object be used as an implicit parameter of a method? For example, I have an array list of Card objects hand, and each Card has a value and a suit. I also have a getter method getValue. Will it work if I write hand.get(i).geValue()? Thanks.

Comment: *Yes*. Why didn't you try it before asking?

Comment: Thanks. And because I wrote in notepad++. I guess I should learn how to do it in eclipse...

Comment: no. notepad++ is fine, but then you take your file, run it through javac, and see if it compiles. No Eclipse necessary, but you should at least run your code to see what happens =)

Answer (score 1):

if you declared it as `ArrayList<Card>`, sure. That's what [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) are for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do casting to `Card` first:

```
((Card)hand.get(i)).getValue();
```

Or you can use the [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html):

```
List<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

And then safely get your value as follows:

```
Card card = hand.get(i).getValue();   
// Here do whatever you want with your card
```